# How to see git logs only for selected module in IDEA version control tab?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, version-control

I've got multiple maven projects opened in IDEA in same window . When I click on version control tab ,it shows history for all changes combined .

I want to see history only for selected module . How to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **Git - Show History** from the context menu of the module in the Project Tree

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `Path` in the `Git` tab:

[image]

where you can select the VCS Roots that you want to see.